# Array defining in Android Application

Tags: android

I want to use the concept of array in my Android Application, I don't know how to do that actually.

So could anybody please help me how to do that on demand.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are talking about arrays in Android through the `res` folder.

Create an `array.xml` inside the `/res/values` folder with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
  <string-array name="names_list">
   <item>John</item>
   <item>Peter</item>
   <item>Charles</item>
  </string-array>
 </resources>
```

You can get that array on your `Activity` by doing:

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names_list);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are alot of different "array" types in java... there are actual arrays like Thorsten showed you and then there are lists, collections and hashes. Take you pick. :) A great place to start learning more about Java is the docs.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

This defines an array of 5 strings:

```
String[] stringArray = new String[5];
```

However, I can not imagine that this is really what you're talking about...

**CLARIFICATION**
If you actually don't know what an array is, then my reply will give you a hint. In case you're talking about something else, this reply should indicate that you're not giving enough detail. You might as well be talking about [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming)...